# Why the service constructor work without new in nest.js controller

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When I see following `nestjs` documentation. I have question about `cat controller`

https://docs.nestjs.com/providers

`constructor(private catsService: CatsService) {}`

① Why the following `constructor` needed ?
this constructor defined `this.catsService = catsService` right ?

② Why the `new` operator doesn't exist ? the above `constructor` seems not be initialized. and seems not work..

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateCatDto } from './dto/create-cat.dto';
import { CatsService } from './cats.service';
import { Cat } from './interfaces/cat.interface';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
    this.catsService.create(createCatDto);
  }

  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.catsService.findAll();
  }
}
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest works by using [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It does this, by reading the types of the controller parameters or the metadata set for them (if using `@Inject()`) and creates the dependencies under the hood for you. In this case, Nest reads the constructor, sees the first parameter is of type `CatsService` and creates a `CatsService` instance to pass to the `CatsController`. This takes a lot of pressure off of the devs to remember to do such things, and keep track of what instances exists (Nest also tracks that and keeps instances Singleton to the best of its abilities). Nest handling all of the class instantiations is why you don't really see the `new` word anywhere. Hopefully that clears things up.

I've noticed you've posted a couple of questions about *how* Nest works recently. If you want to have conversation in a bit of a quicker manner, feel free to [join our Discord](https://discord.gg/nestjs) and ask there.

Comment: @Heisenberg: if an answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. So far you have not accepted one of your recent questions regarding NestJS ...